# How do I update tables in the Android onupgrade SQLiteDatabase event?

Tags: android, sql-update, special-characters, sqlite

I am having issues getting the update to work in the onUpgrade event in the SQLiteDatabase event for an android application.  The data is not getting updated after executing the SQL update when onUpgrade is called.

Below is the code that I am trying to execute, running the application in the emulator.

I also have to reupload the database to the emulator with each run, because I am upgrading from version 1 to 2.

```
String strSpecChar = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString("∩┐╜");
String strSpecCharFilter = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString("%∩┐╜%");
String strReplChar = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString("'");

String strCharReplace = "UPDATE "
  + myTable + " SET "
  + column2 + " = REPLACE(" + column2 + ", " 
                            + strSpecChar + ", " 
                            + strReplChar + ")" 
  + " WHERE " + column2 + " LIKE " + strSpecCharFilter;

db.execSQL(strCharReplace);
```

I have been looking online for a few days trying to get this to work, and without success far, I have searched online, used the debugger, and I also verified that the code above works through the sqlite3 adb shell command line interface before posting my question.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice on this.

*** Edit ***
Thanks for your replies and feedback.

The problem that I'm having is that the data is not being updated.  After running the application, I am still seeing the old data that was there before the update statement was executed.  I am trying to replace the 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (being seen as a black diamond with a white question mark in it) with an apostrophe.

I didn't get any errors in the LogCat when the SQL was executed.

I did previously verify that the SQL works using the sqlite3 command line tool through adb shell.

The log value of strCharReplace:

```
strCharReplace = "UPDATE table SET column2 = REPLACE(payeename, '∩┐╜', '''') WHERE column2 LIKE '%∩┐╜%'"
```

Comment: Glad to hear you searched before posting. However, it would have been really helpful if you could explain what "issues" you have been having with this.

Comment: wIs there any exception that has been thrown? If yes: which one? How does the statement look like when you log it (`strCharReplace`) to the console? Is the result executable in your database (use `abd  shell`, `sqlite3 <database>`).